# Can I bind an image from one form to the control on another

Tags: c#, wpf, image, data-binding

I have two forms, one is an 'editor' type form where I have the ability to select multiple images from the users pc and upload them into the local database where they are stored. This works fine, I can access them and see them populated in my listbox.

However, I also want to be able to show these images on another form, for the sake of saving time - Yes, I must use another form. I am fairly new to data binding, but I still understand it enough to have implemented it quite extensively, I just can't figure out how to databind from the image object on form 2, to the listbox on Form 1. The end idea was to create a slideshow type application (only 1 part of the application).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Form I assume `Window`, so there are multiple way to do this...

1. MVVM - This will have a view model instance bound to window 1 that will hold the URI of the selected images and the same view model instance can be bound to the other window and it will show the images on the other.
2. You **can** refer two elements from two forms if one of the forms has been marked as the `Owner` of another.

E.g. if `Window1` is the OwnerWindow of `Window2` like so...

```
 window2.Owner = window1;
 window2.Show();
```

On `Window1`, bind the `Window.Tag` property with the element's selected items property...

```
 <Window x:Class="...Window1"
         ...
         Tag="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=MyListBox, Mode=OneWay}">
     <ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" .... />
 </Window>
```

Then on `Window2` you could use the data binding to data context for acheiving the same via that `Owner.Tag` property

```
 <Window x:Class="...Window2"
         ...>
     <ListBox x:Name="ThumbnailListBox"
              DataContext="{Binding Owner.Tag, 
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                        AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
 </Window>
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

You can bind directly from the database in the second form. Since you have the images stored in the local database by now, you can easily retrieve them in the second form.

Comment: Yeah that is what I thought too, but I couldn't think how I could only retrieve images specific to each property (real estate software). I was doing this by data binding to a listbox.selecteditem previously.